# Xamarin.iOS - Linker behavior: Link All - Assets images removed

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, assets, xamarin-linker

Has anyone experienced the images loaded in the Assets Catalog of a Xamarin.iOS project being removed when using the Linker behavior: Link All?

I have the following solution structure (simplified):

- MyApp.csproj (shared code)
- MyApp.iOS.csproj (iOS project)

  - Assets

And I compile with the following mtouch arguments:

`--linkskip=MyApp --linkskip=MyApp.iOS`

Besides the fact of the images not showing up, the rest of the app works flawlessly.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.2.5; Xamarin version 17.2.0.177

**Update:**

Interestingly, if I replace the Xamarin.Forms.Image implementations for [FFImageLoading.CachedImage](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading), the images are not affected by the LinkAll configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, trying to create a reproducible sample I came across the problem.

Basically, the following line `CachedImageRenderer.InitImageSourceHandler()`, introduced when using FFImageLoading, was messing up with Xamarin.Forms.Images when the linker was set to LinkAll.

The [documentation of FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API) is not super clear on what this line is for, but removing it fixed the problem.